# Extract articles from its corresponding links from a webpage using scrapy

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Hi I am new to scrapy and I am Trying to extract text from links in a [given webpage](https://www.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business). Here is the code I wrote for the same and after running scrapy crawl article, it gives no module named article. Can you help me find where I am wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class ArticleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'article'
    allowed_domains = ['www.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business']
    start_urls = ['https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.css('span.w_tle a::attr(href)').extract()
        for link in links:
            url = urljoin(response.url, link)
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_article)
    def parse_article(self,response):
        for info in response.css('div.article_content clearfix'):
            yield {'Article':info.css('div.Normal::text').extract()}
```

Comment: You say “it gives no module named article”. I don’t see anything in your code that may cause that. Could you share the traceback of the ImportError exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at your log you'll see `'offsite/filtered': 211,` and that the cause of not getting anything. In order to dodge this you can do two things:

1. Remove `allowed_domains` field
2. Add `dont_filter=True` in your request like:

```py
yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_article, dont_filter=True)
```

I tested your code it does not seems to work properly if you want to get text body so i rewrote it with XPath which I am more comfortable with.

```py
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class ArticleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'article'
    allowed_domains = ['www.timesofindia.indiatimes.com']
    start_urls = ['https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/business']

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//*[@id="c_listing_wdt_1"]//span[1]/a/@href').getall()
        for link in links:
            url = urljoin(response.url, link)
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_article, dont_filter=True)
    def parse_article(self, response):
        print(response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]//arttextxml//div//text()').getall())
        for info in response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]//arttextxml//div//text()').getall():
            yield {'Article':info}
```

> `getall()` can be used instead of `extract()`, they are almost equal.